# openwrt Self-compiled firmware

Tags: openwrt

I want to download wifidog from OpenWRt，then I execute the command：
opkg update
opkg install wifidog
Error:
root@OpenWrt:~# opkg install wifidog
Package wifidog (1.3.0-6) installed in root is up to date.
Collected errors:

- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-nf-reject
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-nf-ipt
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-ipt-core
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-ipt-extra
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-ipt-ipopt
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-nf-conntrack
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-nf-nat
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-ipt-nat
- pkg_hash_check_unresolved: cannot find dependency kernel (= 5.10.107-1-8b0ca0                                                                                                             fcb3d630926cd2eaf086060f89) for kmod-ipt-nat-extra

These missing dependencies were selected when I compiled the firmware
Why is that
[image]

I tried self-compiling the firmware, adding all the missing dependencies, repackaging, and reburning the firmware, but still got an error: missing dependencies
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is your kernel version? Are you in the same version as 5.10.107?

Also, did you try to download that ipk and manually install it? If you are sure that you did enable it at the kernel level, there is no harm in trying to install it with force overriding. Or you could run the binary directly to see if there is an error.

If you really need to make it works, you can always try to cross-compile this package for your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

which version your openwrt? I suggest using apfree-wifidog cause wifidog not maintained for years

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."